# Flask-Login load_user is never called

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

I am using Flask-Login (version 0.2.11) for my project. I initialize it like this:

```
from flask.ext import login

from project import app
from project.database import db
from project.modules.user import User, Anonymous

login_manager = login.LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.anonymous_user = Anonymous
login_manager.login_view = 'frontend.login'

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    print('USER LOADER CALLED')
    return User.query.get( int(id) )
```

`User` is a subclass of `UserMixin` and database model.

When I call `login_user` method for a valid user, it returns true. `login_required` decorator is also working as expected.
However, `current_user` in my templates remains an instance of Anonymous even after submitting the login form. The debug statement in `load_user` never gets printed. I cannot access pages protected with login_required decorator at all.

My other code does not modify `session`, so I do not think it can be the cause of this issue. SECRET_KEY is set in the config.

So, what is wrong with my initialization code?

**EDIT:** It seems that I am able to login if I pass "remember=True" to the function. However, logging in without "remember me" option is not working.

**EDIT (2):** It seems like logging in without "remember me" does not work in Chromium/WebKit-based browsers (Opera 31.0, Vivaldi, Chrome). However, it does work in Firefox.

**SOLUTION:** The issue was running the app on `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` — Chrome does not handle cookies correctly for pages accessed by their IP address.

Comment: Is the client configured to accept cookies?

Comment: @Miguel yes, my browser has never had issues with cookies.

Comment: Regardless, can you double check that there is a `Cookie` header in the requests sent to your Flask server? Because a missing session cookie explains the behavior you describe. Flask-Login gets the user id from the cookie, and then calls the user loader callback with it. If there is no cookie, then user_loader is not called.

Comment: The name of the cookie should be `session`, unless you changed it in the configuration. What are the contents of the `mod` cookie?

Comment: Also, if I use "remember me", `remember_token` cookie appears (see my edit).

Comment: Okay, so the `mod` cookie is probably unrelated, maybe some other app you used in the past. Another question: do you have a `SECRET_KEY` setting in your configuration?

Comment: @Miguel Yes, SECRET_KEY is set. I probably should have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: This is very odd. Did you try at least two browsers, to make sure the problem is on the server? My guess is that this is a browser configuration issue.

Comment: @Miguel I tested it a bit more. Logging in without "remember me" works only in Firefox. It does not work in chromium-based browsers (Opera, Vivaldi, SRWare Iron).